# Is it possible to route incoming traffic permanently in linux?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables

I was trying to route my incoming connections to a teamspeak server on another machine
using below iptables commands

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -s 0/0 -d LOCALIP --dport 9987 -j DNAT --to DESTINATIONIP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -d DESTINATIONIP -j SNAT --to-source LOCALIP
```

It kinda works BUT every user that joins now has my routing server's IP.

Is there a way to somehow just push the client directly to the new IP if it reaches the port on the routing server?

Comment: Is the TeamSpeak server on the same network as your machine?

Comment: No, its in a completely different network

Comment: Is the TeamSpeak server owned by you? (That is, do you have root or system administrator rights on the server OS?)

Comment: And third, are your clients connecting through a DNS domain name, or are they connecting straight to your IP address?

Comment: Yes the TeamSpeak server is owned by me and I have root access to the server, clients are connecting through a domain name which is pointing to the the server I want to redirect from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It kinda works BUT every user that joins now has my routing server's IP.

That's hard to avoid when the servers are far apart. This is happening because you have that SNAT rule in line 2 – and if the final server is on a completely different network, you *need* that SNAT rule in order to force all "reply" traffic back through your routing server as well.

If the SNAT rule was removed, clients' IP addresses would be preserved – but it would create an even bigger problem, as the TeamSpeak server would send responses directly to clients, completely bypassing your "routing" server. This would confuse clients as they sent the request to address X and did not expect to receive response from address Y.

A better way to do this would be to *tunnel* the original packet inside yet another IP packet (using GRE or WireGuard or OpenVPN). Then your routing server would forward everything through the tunnel, and the TeamSpeak server could easily be configured to respond through the tunnel as well, without the need to SNAT anything.

> Is there a way to somehow just push the client directly to the new IP if it reaches the port on the routing server?

If your clients are directly configured for the IP address, then no. There is no generic IP function for this. If the client wants to talk to 1.2.3.4, it *will* talk to 1.2.3.4 – you can't force it to send packets to 5.6.7.8 instead.

This kind of redirection can *only* be achieved as an application-level protocol feature. For example, HTTP has redirects. So if TeamSpeak itself has redirection built-in to its protocol, that can be used. If not, then not. (I'm guessing that's what "TSDNS" is?)

But if your clients are connecting through a domain name, then you can create a ['SRV record'](https://support.teamspeak.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002711418-Does-TeamSpeak-3-support-DNS-SRV-records-) for that domain name and point TS3 clients elsewhere that way.

SRV still depends on application-level support (most programs don't understand it), but at least it's officially documented that TS3 does in fact support using SRV records.

---

Summary:

1. You said that you have a domain name. The best solution in your case would be to use DNS SRV records which TS3 recognizes – that is basically their whole purpose. This way, clients will *directly* go to the specified TS3 server without needing to contact your 'routing' server at all.
2. If you cannot create SRV records, then set up a basic tunnel between the two servers; remove the SNAT rule; change the DNAT rule to use the TS server's "tunnel" IP instead of its public IP; and set up "policy routing" on the TS server so that it knows to respond via the same tunnel.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

It turned out I did add the SRV record but incorrectly yesterday and I didn't think to even search on the official TeamSpeak site for more info.
And the WebPanel of the domain DNS configuration isn't "clear" aswell